# Naming function types

Tags: typescript

Is there a TypeScript equivalent of C#'s Func keyword?

On a preliminary exploration of TypeScript today converting some existing code, I used interface for classes/objects but found myself duplicating function types unnecessarily. Am I missing something?

In the following I've defined an interface for an object type (Data) and would benefit from naming (data: Data) => void too

```
interface Funcs {
    box: (data: Data) => void;
    lbl: (data: Data) => void;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function type `(args) => t` is just an abbreviation for the object type `{(args): t}`, so the following should work:

```
interface Func {
  (data: Data): void;
}

interface Funcs {
  box: Func;
  lbl: Func;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, `Func` takes generic type parameters. Generics are not yet part of the TypeScript language specification - but they are listed on the roadmap.

Having said this, I'm not sure how you intend to use it in this case - are you after this?

Psuedocode:

```
interface Funcs {
    box: Action<Data>;
    lbl: Action<Data>;
}
```

To make your definition shorter (i.e. I accept a parameter of type Data and return void). I used `Action` as there is no return value, but you could think of `Func<Data, ResultType>` equally here.

In any case, we will have to wait for generics and see how they are implemented and if they allow this kind of use.